# Solve second order differential inequality

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a function such that it is continuos and for each point the 1st and 2nd derivative of $f$ at this point is well-defined.  Suppose that $f<0$ or $f>0$ on $\mathbb R$.

**Q** Can we  find an $f$ satisfying the inequality: 
$$-y''/y>k,$$
for some positive real number $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such an inequality cannot hold. Without loss of generality we can assume that $f > 0$ on $\Bbb R$, otherwise consider $-f$ instead.

Then $f'' < - k f < 0$, i.e. $f$ is strictly concave, and $f'$ is strictly decreasing.

Now choose any $x_0$ with $f'(x_0) \ne 0$ ($f$ is not constant!) and show that either $\lim_{x \to \infty } f(x) = -\infty$ or $\lim_{x \to -\infty } f(x) = -\infty$, depending on the sign of $f'(x_0)$.